# Multiple cameras and ScissorStack?

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I'm currently trying to make a game, and I'm still novice with using cameras, and I'm thinking that two `OrthographicCamera`s may be necessary, but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way, or even how to do so.

Basically, I want this to be the layout for it:

[image: Mock-Up Layout]

The **Main Area** is where the main stuff is, which is a Server Interface. The **Game Level** is where the actual game part is in. I am currently using a `ScissorStack` to cut the region, but with this demo, results make me question how to do this:

```
public class TestScissorStackAndCamera extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private int width, height;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
        camera.position.set(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
        createSprite();
    }

    private void createSprite() {
        Pixmap map = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);
        map.setColor(Color.RED);
        map.fillRectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        map.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        map.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
        map.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
        Texture texture = new Texture(map);
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); // The Question!
        batch.begin();
        {
            Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20);
            ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, batch.getTransformMatrix(), area, scissors);
            ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
            batch.draw(sprite, 0, 0);
            batch.flush();
            ScissorStack.popScissors();
        }
        batch.end();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "ScissorStack & Camera Test";
        config.resizable = false;
        new LwjglApplication(new TestScissorStackAndCamera(), config);
    }
}
```

**Questioning batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)**
I marked a line in the code with a comment, `The Question!`, which is what is affecting the results. If I don't have it, using the `camera.translate(...)` method, the image is drawn at `(0, 0)` but what it does is it moves what part is viewed. If I do have that line, when I use the `camera.translate(...)` method, the image is drawn respectively to the position of the camera.

In respect to the game that I'm currently developing, it behaves awkwardly without the `projectionMatrix` not being set, but when I do set it, it messes up the positioning of the rest of the game. I even added some testing features, and it's not rendering inside of the correct `ScissorStack`

How could I go about setting up two cameras, or what could I do to set up what I'm trying to correctly and efficiently?

With my actual game (not the mock-up) this is what it is doing. It should be rendering inside of the red lines, but it's not:

[image: Results from program]

If you'd like to see my current code for my GameLevel that is handling the `ScissorStack` and `OrthographicCamera`:

```
public GameLevel(int x, int y, int displayWidth, int displayHeight) {
    this.x = x; // x = 10
    this.y = y; // y = 10
    this.displayWidth = displayWidth; // displayWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - x - 10
    this.displayHeight = displayHeight; // displayHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y - 120
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(displayWidth / 2, displayHeight / 2, 0);
    // FBLAGame.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();
    init();
}

...

@Override
public void render() {
    Rectangle area = new Rectangle(x, y, displayWidth, displayHeight);
    Rectangle scissor = new Rectangle();
    Matrix4 matrix = FBLAGame.batch.getTransformMatrix();
    ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, matrix, area, scissor);
    ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissor);
    renderLevel();
    FBLAGame.batch.flush();
    ScissorStack.popScissors();
    Pixmap map = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
    map.setColor(Color.RED);
    map.drawRectangle((int) area.x, (int) area.y, (int) area.width, (int) area.height);
    Texture t = new Texture(map);
    map.dispose();
    FBLAGame.batch.draw(t, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: If i understood it correctly you want to draw the `Levle` and some kind of `HUD`. For this i would suggest to first draw the `Level`, with the `levelCamera` and then draw the `HUD` with the `hudCamera`. While the `levelCamera` can move arround and show different parts of the `Level`, the `hudCamera` should always stay at the same place

Comment: Would I set the projection matrices every time I would draw each one of them?

Comment: If you are using the same `SpriteBatch` for the `HUD` and the `level`, then you need to set the `projectionMatrix` 2 times per render loop: Once at the begining, set the `projectionMatrix` of your `levelCamera` and once after drawing the leven, set the `projectionMatrix` of your `hudCamera`. If you use 2 `SpriteBatch`es, you only need to set the `projectionMatrix` of your `levelBatch` every renderloop, as the `levelCamera` can "walk" arround. The `hudCamera` stays at the same point. Just make sure you call `levelBatch.end` before calling `hudBatch.begin()`